# casperjs include prerequisite scripts

Tags: casperjs

I want to include casper.js scripts in each file that perform prerequisite actions, like logging in. How can I do this? It seems that the `--pre` flag is only available when casperjs is in test mode. Can I `require` the scripts before I start the dependent scripts? If so, how do I specify an execution order? Do I just have to write a separate launcher process to handle this?

If I just try a simple `require('login.js')` at the head of the file, PhantomJS complains:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'casper'
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a collection of script filepaths to include in every page loaded with `clientScripts` like this :

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts:  [
        'includes/jquery.js',      // These two scripts will be injected in remote
        'includes/underscore.js'   // DOM on every request
    ]
});
```